# javascript polling a neat way needed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, signalr

I have a web page which provides real time monitoring.
Basically the page refreshes portion of its contents each second by calling a webform which actually returns an xml with updated data. This way is very simple, but it really doesn't sound neat to me.

The js code it's:

```
setInterval(function () {
    GetAgents(responseId);
}, 1000);


//get Agents from b64 encoded xml
function AgentsHtml(b64) {
    var html = "<div style=\"float: left; width: 45%; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 1px; box-shadow: " +
        "4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07); border-color: rgb(186,186,186); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;\">\r\n@@agentdata@@\r\n</div>\r\n";

    var xml = "";
    var retVal = "";

    try {
        xml = decode64(b64);

        if (xml != " ") {
            var xmlDoc = $($.parseXML(xml));

            var Agents = xmlDoc.find("WcfAgent");

            Agents.each(function () {

                var ActiveState = $(this).find('ActiveState').text();
                var ActivityToken = "" + $(this).find('ActivityToken').text();
                var Avalabilty = $(this).find('Avalabilty').text();
                var Name = $(this).find('Name').text();
                var SipUri = $(this).find('SipUri').text();
                var StateColor = $(this).find('StateColor').text();

                var pic = "/extensions/utsi001/images/dispo55x55.jpg";

                if (ActivityToken != "" && ActivityToken != "off-work") {
                    pic = "/extensions/utsi001/images/conv55x55.jpg";
                }

                if (ActivityToken == "" && ActiveState == "UnavailableForIncomingCall" &&
                    (Avalabilty == "DoNotDisturb" ||
                     Avalabilty == "Busy")) {
                    pic = "/extensions/utsi001/images/pausa55x55.jpg";
                }
                if (ActivityToken == "" && Avalabilty == "Offline") {
                    pic = "/extensions/utsi001/images/off55x55.png";
                }


                var agent =
"                <div style=\"float: left; width: 79%\">\r\n" +
"                <p>" + Name + "</p>\r\n" +
"                <p style=\"font-size: 12px; padding-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px; color: rgb(160,160,160);\">" + SipUri + "</p>\r\n" +
"                <div style=\"height: 12px; background-color:" + StateColor + "; border:solid 1px rgb(186,186,186)\"></div>\r\n" +
"                    </div>\r\n" +
"                <div style=\"float: right; width: 20%; margin-top: 5px\">\r\n" +
"                    <img alt=\"\" src=\"" + pic + "\" />\r\n" +
"                </div>"

                agent = html.replace("@@agentdata@@", agent);

                retVal += agent;

            });

        }
        else {
            retVal = "";
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        retVal = b64 + "<br />" + err;
    }

    return retVal;
}


    //return agents ajax call
    function GetAgents(responseId) {

    link = "/somewhere/agents.aspx";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: link,
        data: "",
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success: function (b64) {
            var res = document.getElementById(responseId);
            if (res != null && res != undefined) {

                res.innerHTML = AgentsHtml(b64);
            }

        },
        error: function (e) {
            var res = document.getElementById(responseId);
            if (res != null && res != undefined) {
                res.innerHTML = e.responseText;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The reason i did an ajax call to a web form it's because i get data from a self hosted wcf service which can not directly be invoked cross domain using javascript.

Please. Consider the above code as an example. In my page i don't need only one data update.. there are several.. agents (above), incoming calls, call queue status etc..

**From this point it's a new edit**

So thanks to Avner's comment i did some tests with SignalR and i almost solved my problem.
**To be clear the problem was: "find a way to avoid ajax calls fired any given second with setInterval"**

Within the windows service which hosts mentioned WCF service i added also a SignalR webapp (hub) and seems to working fine.

This is the hub class code, since my needs actually are to push informations to the connected web clients after some events occurred in my server service:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    //content will be a base64String containing a xml sheet
    public void CallRefreshAgents(String content)
    {
        Clients.All.refreshAgents(content);
    }

    //...
    // others methods just like the above       

    private static IHubContext _context = null;
    public static IHubContext HubContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
                _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

            return _context;
        }
    }
}
```

And so just handling changing on agents presence i can push information by a simple call:

```
//pushVal it's a base64String containing a xml sheet
MyHub.HubContext.Clients.All.refreshAgents(pushVal);
```

In my Asp.Net Web app i only added references to jquery.signalr.js and in the monitoring page the js client it's very very simple:

```
<head>
    <script .... Al references needed .... </script>
    <!-- service auto published js code -->
    <script src="http://mySignalSelfHostedEndPoint/signalr/hubs"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hub = null;
    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://mySignalSelfHostedEndPoint/signalr";
        hub = $.connection.myHub;
        $.connection.hub.start().done();
    });
</script>
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    //for initialization only during load/reload of the page
    $(document).ready(
            GetAgents("<%=DivIds.sections%>"));

    $(function () {
        hub.client.refreshAgents = function (b64) {
            document.getElementById("<%=DivIds.sections%>").innerHTML = AgentsHtml(b64);
        };
    });
</script>
```

**Is MyHub class well implemented?**
I don't really need clients which can call "CallRefreshAgents", afterall i would like to forbid that kind of calls occur

Comment: Have you looked at signalr? https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: @Avner [signalr](http://signalr.net/) very good advice.. Unfortunately i can't use third party libraries. But i think i'm on the right way thanks to: "..You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables bi-directional communication between the browser and server." from signalr web site

Comment: I didn't noticed that signalr came from Microsft so like jQuery it's compliant with my company policy :-) i'll get into..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my hub class as follow.

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    internal static void RefreshAgents(String pushVal)
    {
        HubContext.Clients.All.refreshAgents(pushVal);
    }

    //other methods like the one above
    //..

    private static IHubContext _context = null;
    private static IHubContext HubContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
                _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

            return _context;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it sounds good.
So, only inside my namespace within the service i can just call MyHub.RefreshAgents("...."); or whatever...

As expected everything works fine and no changes were needed at clients side.